# Amazon AWS-Web server not accessible through Barracuda WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-server, windows-server-2012-r2, barracuda

I have just started working with AWS in my new role and have come across setting a new test environment in AWS. As part of this new setup, I am setting up a test web server and this web server has to have an existing Barracuda(AWS) WAF service sitting in front of it. I have configured the WAF service in Barracuda as per the other services that are configured for our existing servers. The test web server is set up like a normal web server should be and I have installed an SSL certificate on it as well.

When I try to access the web server(Windows server 2012 r2) internally within the server itself it is working fine over both http and https. But when I try to access it using the internet from out side, it keeps thinking for a while and throws the following error "*The requested service is temporarily unavailable. It is either overloaded or under maintenance. Please try later*."

I have tried telnet to port 80(I have setup a redirect service as well on WAF) and 443 for the web server IP and it works fine from any where and I can telnet into it but still get the above error when trying to go through browser. What am I missing here?? Any help would be appreciated.

I also had a look at the debugging console in browser when I get the above error and following is the error message that I get.

https://xx.xx.xx.xxx/favicon.ico (xx-- Because I cannot disclose the IP address for obvious reasons) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

Answer (score 0):

Alright...since I was not able to get any help here...I decided to contact Barracuda support. It turns out the reason why i was having an issue was that i did not have a route specified for this new IP address in the advanced networking tab in advanced section of the WAF. As soon as I did that, it was all working.